# PHP/Mysql Load Data Local Infile

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have tried everything that I can think of, but for some reason I cannot get this to work.

I have a piece of PHP code that loads a locally stored CSV file into a MySQL database. It works perfectly in one script:

```
$query = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \''.$arp_input.'\' INTO TABLE arp_import FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\' (not_used,account_number,check_serial,issue_date,amount,transaction_code,additional_text)';
```

However, I need to do the same thing (load a CSV) in another script that does essentially the same thing, but generates a different format. Here is the query:

```
$query = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \''.$ap_input.'\' INTO TABLE ap_import FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\' (account_number,check,paiddate,amount)';
```

But when I run the second script with the above query, I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check,paiddate,amount)' at line 1
```

When I take out the field listing at the end of the second query, it only imports ONE line from the file and that is it, even when I tried the \n delimiter, \r, and both \r\n.

I have tried everything that I can think of. These two PHP scripts are running on the same server and they are both accessing the same remote MySQL server. What am I missing here?

Comment: `$ap_input` v.s. `$arp_input` (`R`)?. Is that intention, or is perhaps $ap_input a type and you're really trying `.. INFILE '' INTO ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check is a reserved word according to the MySQL documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Ahh, so incredibly simple. That was it. Now I need to figure out why it is only taking one line..

Answer (score 0):

**`check`** is a reserved word in MySQL ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html ). You should enclose it in back-ticks (`) in your sql sentence: